# Section at bottom of screen that doesn't respond to onpress event, what's causing this?

Tags: react-native-ios

I'm working on an existing React-Native app, and in the iOS version, there's a problem where a portion of the bottom of the screen does not respond. At first it was thought to be on a specific screen, but upon further investigation, it was found to be affecting other screens as well. The control used on the first screen where the problem was noticed is TouchableOpacity, but a rectangular section in the middle at the bottom of the screen does not respond, but in either corner at the bottom of the screen it does respond. Another screen has a ListView, and if you attempt to scroll from that same bottom middle area, it won't, but everywhere else, it will. This is evident in both the simulator and on the physical device. It acts like there's something in the road floating over the top of everything.

I've tried using the Accessibility Inspector to identify the cause, but this hasn't revealed anything.

[image: Screen Example]

The highlighted area in the screenshot above is where I'm referring to.

To complicate things further, this problem doesn't exist in the Android version.

Has anyone experienced this before, and if so, what was the cause and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** I've now determined the cause is an Animated View that's hanging about, it seems not all the child elements within it are having their opacity set to 0. I've attempted to address this using pointerEvents, but this just moves the problem to a different child element.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be that the parent was having it's height changed during the show and hide events to avoid this same issue in Android, so we need to only change it if the platform is Android.

```
this.setState({height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 50: 0});
```